# How to add a Windows Firewall ports to Printer using a Config File

Tags: printer, services, file-sharing, windows-firewall, ports

I need to create a config file for Windows Firewall ports to printers. But I didn't get any ideas from the internet. If anyone knows can anyone suggest me.

Comment: Your printer isn't running Windows Firewall. Please edit your question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you are trying to tell WFW to allow ports like 9100 or 515.

It is possible to set up Windows Firewall from a command line. That means you could create a batch file or PowerShell script to set it up. If necessary, that batch file could read your config file.

The following command tells WFW to enable port 515 (LPR):

```
netsh firewall add portopening port=515 protocol=tcp mode-enable
```

Is that  what you are trying to do?

[This web page](https://lizardsystems.com/articles/configure-windows-firewall-using-command-line/) gives more lots more details, including additional things you may want to set up, e.g. file and printer sharing.

Another possible answer to your question is to export/import Windows Firewall settings, as shown in this image:
[image]

Comment: i must allow the printer to use only two-port of the windows firewall

Comment: Most TCP/IP printers need only one: 9100. The other one, 515 (LPR) is rarely used these days. If you allow only those 2, other applications will fail though.

Comment: Is there any alternative way that we can configure the windows firewall ports that communicate with the printer?

Comment: Where and how do I have to add this port to the windows firewall? Whether I have to add in inbound or outbound, whether the ports are TCP or UDC please specif

Comment: The command I gave adds port 515. Substitute 9100 if that's the one you need